# Problems to install waffle package

Tags: r, waffle-chart

I'm trying install the waffle package but i'm not having sucess. When i do require, the folowwing message appers to me:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
>   versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    there is no package called ‘Rttf2pt1’.

I already tried install the `Rttf2pt1` package before the waffle, but appears a error message when i do require:

> In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,
>   logical.return = TRUE,  :   there is no package called ‘Rttf2pt1’.

Comment: To install packages, you use `install.packages()`, not `library()`. The latter only loads previously installed packages. So did you run `install.packages("Rttf2pt1")`? How did you try to install `waffle`? What R version are you running?

Comment: i used install.packages for both packages. i just show the last outuput, because the error shows up when i tried require. I'm using 3.4.2 version.

Comment: If the require didn't work, that means there was probably an error during the install step. That would be the import error message to share.

Comment: `waffle` package author here confirming that this is a pkg management issue on your system vs a waffle pkg issue itself

Comment: error message for Rttf2pt1 package:   O sistema nÆo pode encontrar o caminho especificado.
Makefile.win:15: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
Warning: execução do comando 'make --no-print-directory -f "Makefile.win"' teve status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rttf2pt1'
* removing 'C:/Users/Camila/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rttf2pt1'

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a setup issue. Using `.libPaths()`, see where your libraries are stored and then ensure that both `Rttf2pt1` and `waffle` are residing where your `R` basic library packages are stored. If not, move the folders corresponding these packages to the folder where basic `R` libraries are and that ought to solve this issue.

So do-

```
install.packages("Rttf2pt1", dependencies = TRUE)
library(Rttf2pt1)
install.packages("waffle", dependencies = TRUE)
library(waffle)
```

And then check in the library (`C:/Users/user name/Documents/R/win-library/3.4`) and you should see folders named `waffle` and `Rttf2pt1`, if everything worked well.

If that still doesn't work, try the following

```
install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/waffle")
library(waffle)
```

Comment: Thank you, Indrajeet. I moved the waffle package but i can´t so the same with Rttf2pt1, because he can´t be installed:                                                        2: In install.packages("Rttf2pt1") :
  installation of package ‘Rttf2pt1’ had non-zero exit status
> require(Rttf2pt1)
Carregando pacotes exigidos: Rttf2pt1
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘Rttf2pt1’

Comment: @CamilaRibeiro Hmm, have you tried reinstalling it `install.packages("waffle", dependencies = TRUE)` and then rechecking with `.libPaths()`?

Comment: @CamilaRibeiro If everything goes fine, you should see both of these packages (`Rttf2pt1` and `waffle`) in the folder `C:/Users/user name/Documents/R/win-library/3.4`

Comment: I tried with dependencies=TRUE, but the Rttf2pt1 continues not installed. :(  I looked in the folder, just waffle package shows up.                                                                                                               > require("Rttf2pt1")
Carregando pacotes exigidos: Rttf2pt1
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘Rttf2pt1’

Comment: @CamilaRibeiro Don't use `require(Rttf2pt1)`. Do `install.packages("Rttf2pt1", dependencies = TRUE)` and then `library(Rttf2pt1)`

Comment: @CamilaRibeiro See my edited response. I provide another way to install a package that may resolve this issue.